# HTML image-uploading: How does an image file get sent to a server?

Tags: html, forms, http, encoding, image-uploading

**I am NOT asking how to setup a `form submit = ...` or an `<input  type = file ...`.**

What 'format' does a .jpg take in order to 'move' from a user's pc, through the internet, to a server?

I looked through `my_typeFileInput.files[0]` but this is all I found:

```
lastModified     :  457194076140
lastModifiedDate : Date {Sat Mar 05 2016 11:07:56 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
name             : "my_image.jpg"
size             : 1757295
type             : "image/jpeg"
```

Obviously this is not enough to transport a .jpg's data across the internet to a server. I expected to see a long 1.7MB string of data that represents the .jpg.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4 has an example that should shed some light. And if you want/need more detail, head over to the RFC, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388

Comment: interesting, especially 17.13.4 ... it explained what the `enctype=multipart/form-data`   data structure looks like ... ... unfortunately I did not see where it explained what format a .jpg is converted to ... though that article (17.13.4) did suggest where within the multipart/form-data the .jpg would be stored ...

Comment: You see where for the text file it just says, `Content-Type: text/plain`? That means, the text file content will be embedded as-is, without any additional escaping or encoding. And for the image, it says `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` – that means any sequence of octets, so basically the same: Just the un-encoded, binary image data. […]

Comment: […] That could lead to problems of course, if the text file or the image were to contain the same byte sequence as the chosen boundary – the value in the example is `AaB03x` (in reality longer, randomly generated strings would be used), and that might as well occur inside the text or image – so instead of putting the “plain” data into the email source, a form of encoding might be used after all – like base64 for the binary image data, and quoted-printable for the text.

Comment: ... ugggh ... I missed the line `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` ... well that answers the question then ... if would like to submit a very brief summary as an Answer, that would be great ... I can go back in to your Answer and fill in the longer description ... but you will get the credit for Answer ...

Comment: Happy to. I basically just copy&pasted what my comments contained so far; feel free to add/modify with your own findings. Or, if you have more than just bits to add (maybe you’ve encountered additional documents/examples, that were helpful to your understanding), add a self-answer – those are [always welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) & good for some points too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4 has an example of what a request of type `multipart/form-data` looks like, that should shed some light.

And if you want/need more detail, head over to the RFC, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388

In the mentioned example, you see where for the text file it just says, `Content-Type: text/plain?` That means, the text file content will be embedded as-is, without any additional escaping or encoding applied. And for the image, it says `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` – that means any sequence of octets, so basically the same: Just the un-encoded, binary image data.

That could lead to problems of course, if the text file or the image were to contain the same byte sequence as the chosen boundary – the value in the example is `AaB03x` (in reality longer, randomly generated strings would be used), and that might (plus the leading two `==`, together they make up the boundray string) as well occur inside the text or image – so instead of putting the “plain” data into the email source, a form of encoding might be used after all – like base64 for the binary image data, and quoted-printable for the text.

Comment: CBroe ... hello .. did you see the edits I made to your answer?? ... thanks